# serialize a list of objects in json in Django

Tags: django, json, serialization

In my python code in views.py, i have made a list of Object instances.  For example, if one of my objects in models.py is Sentence, then I at one point have an list of Sentences:

```
sentenceList = [Sentence1,Sentence2,...,SentenceN]
```

I have been happily using the template language in Django to send this off to a template where I can loop through the sentences in a template, but I am now implamenting some AJAX functionality, and would like to send something similar to this list "sentenceList" through a serialization through an AJAX portal.

It seems that I am between two worlds here though: the regular python JSON seiralizer, which serializes lists and python object, and simplejson, which only deals with pure Django Model queries.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I should handle this (including not using lists of object instances if it is for some reason not good form)?

Thank you!

-Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The Django serializer should be able to deal with a regular list of Django objects, [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/?from=olddocs):

> (Actually, the second argument can be any iterator that yields Django objects, but it'll almost always be a QuerySet).